# My Rails Engine depends on my parent app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I want to use Rails engine to modularize my current app. I have read a number of articles about engines including [TaskRabbit](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/)'s and [Pothibo](http://pothibo.com/2014/02/rails-engine-alternative-modularization/)'s posts.

I have a Rails app where I want the parent app to contain all the user tables. The engines I want to mount in the app will be dependent on the parent app, which contains all the user models. While I have this working, I'm unsure as to whether this is bad practice, as my engine will be unable to run without the parent app. The main idea to do this was to modularize the code. While Pothibo's article suggests namespacing within the same app, I like the freedom of managing a separate codebase altogether. Would appreciate some advice as to best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there are two major use cases for Rails engines:

1) Reuse functionality in multiple applications.  This is the most common use case.

2) Provide a migration path to split a monolithic application into smaller apps (micro services).  You can for example start by splitting them out into an engine in the same git repository and mount them by using `gem 'xxx', path: 'engines/xxx'`.  Then later split out further to separate code repositories and/or host as a separate application.

Generally I would advise against no 2, unless the application is big enough to allocate the different engines to different teams.  Disadvantages would be things like complications when you have dependencies between different engine code bases or db tables.  Advantages are things like less tests to run, less code to take ownership of, etc.

You might find these interesting:

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators

http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/